# How to translate and list every error of the form for the user

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-forms, angular-validation

I have multiple forms with over 30 input fields sorted by category in different tabs. Errors on submit are shown under the form fields.

How can I display all validation errors in a list with both the field name and validation error? Field name and error message also need to be translated into german.

This is the code I am trying to use so far:

```
 getFormValidationErrors() {
    const errors = [];
    Object.keys(this.form.controls).forEach(key => {

        const controlErrors: ValidationErrors = this.form.get(key).errors;
        if (controlErrors != null) {
            Object.keys(controlErrors).forEach(keyError => {
                errors.push({
                    'field': key,
                    'error': keyError,
                    'value': controlErrors[keyError]
                });
            });
        }
    });

    console.log(errors);

    return JSON.stringify(errors);
}
```

This is the output in the html so far:

```
[{"Field":"name","Error":"required","value":true},{"Field":"official_name","Error":"required","value":true},{"Field":"address_zip","Error":"notInRange","value":true},{"Field":"address_zip","Error":"required","value":true},{"Field":"address_city","Error":"required","value":true},{"Field":"tenant","Error":"required","value":true}]
```

What I am aiming to display is something like this (but also translated into German):

```
Name: Required, Official Name: Required
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm I edited my question, showing the code I tried using so far.

Comment: Is your errors array getting values when you do errors ?

Comment: @Eudz it does show all errors. Just the translation and formatting is what's missing.

Comment: @ohnoe for the translation, I guess you can use `i18n` : https://angular.io/guide/i18n

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a formatting issue more than anything else. Why not:

Instead of

```
errors.push({
    'field': key,
    'error': keyError,
    'value': controlErrors[keyError]
});
```

do

```
if (controlErrors[keyError]) {
    errors.push({
        this.getFieldLabel(key): this.getErrorLabel(error)
    });
}
```

where the getFieldLabel and getErrorLabel functions are responsible for translating/fetching. You may not even need the object format - a string might work for you - not sure how you are dealing with rendering the text.